# JSON - How to get more than 100 Objects per page when using fetch API (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch-api

I'm using hotsapi.net

You can request paginated data, where each page has a max of 100 objects. But i'm struggling to figure out how to get all the data on one page. Or if that's not possible, a way to loop through all the pages and collect the data.

I'm familiar with doing simple API fetch, but I've never dealt with pages. Especially when there are 100 to 150 pages of data that I need to filter through. I've looked around on the net, and that's helped me come to what's shown below.

So far I have this:

```
function fetchMetaData(){
let i;
let apiData = [];
for (i = 20; i>0; i--) {
    apiData.push(fetch('apiurlwithpage?= i'));
}
Promise.all(apiData)
    .then(responses => {
        let processedResponses = [];
        responses.map(response => {
            processedResponses.push(response);
        })
    })
}
```

`processedResponses` ends up giving me an array of responses. I'm not even sure if that's what I need. You can see it here:

[image]

Comment: an array of responses isn't too much of a problem - you can easily combine the arrays using Javascript, especially if they have the same structure then it's not difficult at all. If it's not possible to get the API to return you all the data at once (and we can't really advise you on the API specifics, you need to check the documentation instead), then make combining the arrays the focus of your research.

Comment: The problem with `Promise.all` is that it makes all calls concurrently, leading to many `429: too many requests`. Try to make the calls one after the other, and after each response, keep pushing the results in a global array.